# How can I make "style.property" work on multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to make this script work on multiple elements.

This script doesn't work if I don't add the [0] next to "tooltipSpan" in "tooltipSpan.style". But I want it to work on multiple elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tooltipSpan = $('.hover-infobulle');

    if (tooltipSpan.length) {
        window.onmousemove = function (e) {
            var x = e.clientX, y = e.clientY;
            tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
            tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
        };
    }
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The jQuery [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) is the function to modify the style property of all elements in the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the elements with a `for` statement.

… or just use the jQuery `css()` method since you *already have a jQuery object*.

To quote the documentation:

> ```
> $( this ).css( "color", "red" );
> ```

Replace `$( this )` with the jQuery object you already have and `"color", "red"` with the property and value you want to change.

Comment: How can I use the `css()` method on my script ? I looked at the documentation but I'm a bit lost. Sorry, I'm a beginner :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in having multiple tooltips at the exact same position. Put all the tooltips into another element, i.e. #tooltip, then move that around. Append tooltips to that element then.

Comment: I don't understand : how is that at the "exact same position" ? 
I have actually multiple dots on a silhouette, and when the user hover one or other dot, I want it to display a tooltip (just when it's on hover). A user can't have two tooltips displayed at the same time.

Comment: If you set tooltipSpan.style.top of all tooltips, they are all at the same position.

Comment: (Sorry, I added precisions, I'm new on stackoverflow!)

Comment: Yeah, but do you need multiple tooltipSpans at all then? Can't you just have one, and change its content depending on the hovered element?